# Why the bootstrap card not aligning side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am working on a Flask project where I am displaying user information from the database on a bootstrap card. I am using jinja2 to loop through an object statuses

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {% if statuses %}
      **{% for status in statuses %}**
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/no_profile.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ status.username }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ status.biography }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ status.interests }}</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      <h2>There are no statuses</h2>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

However I am expecting the cards to appear side by side but they are stacking for all the statuses or entries that are fetched from the database [snapshot of how the image is coming out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfQtB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think you put your {% forloop %} a bit too soon.
Try this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {% if statuses %}
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row mt-4">
          **{% for status in statuses %}**
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/no_profile.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ status.username }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ status.biography }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ status.interests }}</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
  {% else %}
      <h2>There are no statuses</h2>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: my browser is showing that you answered first :)

Comment: You definitely did, as I was answering it popped it saying new answer added. Though I cant seem to get a decent code highlighter working, tried forcing `lang-py` and `lang-python`, but after first `.container` highlighting is goes off-piste.

Comment: Thank you so much.@Rok Klancar

Comment: @Ashford Please mark the correct answer (green checkmark by the upvote and downvote button)

Answer (score 1):

You are including `.container` and `.row` in your `for` loop output? Try moving them to the `if` output

```py
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if statuses %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mt-4">
                **{% for status in statuses %}**
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/no_profile.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ status.username }}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ status.biography }}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ status.interests }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <h2>There are no statuses</h2>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```